# Footer and Page Number at the right side and left side

Tags: page-numbering, footer

I'm using these packages

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,left=1cm, 
right=1cm,includehead=false, includefoot=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\sc Ehsan Benabbas SOP | \thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\sc ehsanbenabbas@gmail.com}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

The problem is, I just have the right and left of the footer on the odd pages and on the even pages, I just have a simple number in the middle of footage as a page number. But I want to have the right and left footer on all the pages. Pleas, Help me out here.

Comment: I made your code a MWE by just adding lipsum in a document environment... And it has not the problem you mentioned. Please test it and add more configurations of your real file until the problem will shown in your output

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but I had `\thispagestyle{plain}` at the even pages! So, I deleted it and the problem solved.